# Can the word 'stops ' be used instead of 'stop'?

Tags: who-whom

"Anyone who stops learning is old"- Is the sentence correct? Can the word 'stops ' be used instead of 'stop'?

Comment: Grammatically, the sentence is fine. Philosophically, who knows. And not only can the word "stops" be used, you need to use "stops" because the subject, "anyone," is singular.

Comment: This is a very basic grammar rule, [subject-verb agreement](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.chompchomp.com/presentations/svagreement.ppt&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwijssiU45HSAhUM4GMKHXgrAq8QFggTMAQ&usg=AFQjCNHWd4NOCRuU_9AvyCxTUWPU-maPXA)

Comment: Btw, you should provide a reason why you think *stops* or *stop* is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence

> Anyone who stops learning is old

is *grammatically and metaphorically correct* and understandable, but may not be *literally* correct since it is possible young children may stop learning, especially those in unstable areas.

"Stops" is the correct verb to use.